# Unable to import the value of the variable from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to store the *value* of css id from a webpage using `SQLite3`. For this i made a *function* where i can store those values inside it. And to retrieve each value i put a for loop on the variable of the other file. But it is giving me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/pc 21/Desktop/Crawl_jar/D_scraper.py", line 35, in <module>
    class_Name = "." + str(i)
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

**MAIN.py :** (this is a piece of code)

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\pc 21\Desktop\Crawl_jar\test.db')

def on_clicked(name):
    on_clicked.xcv = name
    print(on_clicked.xcv)
    conn.execute(f"""INSERT INTO Classes (id) VALUES ("{name}");""")
```

**Other file:**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\pc 21\Desktop\Crawl_jar\test.db')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM classes")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for i in rows:
    print(i)

class_Name = "." + str(i)
```

I think that the database is empty. What i am doing wrong?? Because it is not printing anything.

> Yeah i got the answer myself. It can be solved by putting `cur.commit()` at the end. And it will work with the same code i posted above.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `i` outside the `for` loop? If the table is empty, it will not be set to anything.

Comment: BTW, `fetchall()` returns a list of lists, so `i` will be a list, not an id number.

Comment: So as to get the value of what i have stored in rows. That's what i have done in my other files too, but i don't know why this isn't working??

Comment: So what to use then ?? against the ```fetchall()``` function?

Comment: You're fetching multiple rows, don't you want to do something with every row? If you use `i` after the loop, it's just the last row.

Comment: And if you don't need to process every row, why do you have a loop?

Comment: Yeah my table has only one column, i.e ```id```. Should i use ```fetchone()```

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman read the 1st comment. you can't access "i" like this buddy. keep one tab before   >>> "class_Name = "." + str(i)"

Comment: Ignore `main.py` completely when debugging `other file`. `other file` doesn't care how the value got into the database, just that its there. So, `classes` holds a column of ids. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Yeah i was right!! It isn't storing any value in the database. I just printed out this by commenting all the lines below. And it was blank....

Comment: `main.py` keeps putting ids into the database. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman - on non-windows operating systems "Classes" (main.py) and "classes" (other file) may be different table.s

Comment: Main.py should put id's into the database, and i want it to print the data stored in the database into another file, as you can see in my post.

Comment: I Have windows.

Comment: Okay it's solved!! i just forgot to put ```.commit()``` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `i` inside the loop. And use `i[0]` to get the ID value, since `i` is a list.

```
for i in rows:
    print(i)
    class_Name = "." + str(i[0])
    # use class_Name in code here
```

Comment: Its a list because its the entire column. OP has a bigger problem of trying to figure out which id is wanted. Run `main.py` twice, what does other file want?

Comment: hey @Barmar i was right!! It isn't storing any value in the database. I just printed out this by commenting all the lines below. And it was returning me blank...

Comment: Okay it's solved!! i just forgot to put ```.commit()``` at the end.